# tel anchor link not working with jqtouch and phonegap

Tags: cordova, anchor, jqtouch, iscroll4

I'm using phonegap with jqtouch and am trying to very simply open the phone's native phone app and prompt a call. I've tried all sorts of variations on the following:

```
<a href="tel:[NUMBER]" class="greenButton>Call number</a>
```

I've tried rel="external"

I've tried using href="tel://"

I've tried target="_blank"

I've tried target="_webapp"

I've even tried adding class="tel" and using jQuery to call $(location).attr('href',this.href);

Basically, jqtouch must be intercepting links to do it's thing and I can't figure out how to make it do things normally!

I've found something odd however...
If I wrap the link in an iscroll wrapper it works.

```
<div class="s-scrollwrapper">
<a href="tel:[NUMBER]" class="greenButton">Call number</a>
</div>
```

I obviously don't want to settle for this because it screws up formatting and makes the button scrollable and is pointless. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did turn out to be the way jqtouch intercepts click events and prevents default behaviour. The way I ended up "fixing" it was to put an 's-scrollwrapper' div around the content on the page with the call button. I needed to do this anyway for all screens of the app but as for this datazombies fork, it probably needs a better way to implement tel links.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a problem with iScroll that I have managed to solve by adding the following option:

```
  var options = {
    //other options
    onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
      var target = e.target;
      while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;
      if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA' && target.tagName != 'A') e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
  var myScroll = new iScroll(wrap, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
<a href="tel:[NUMBER]" rel="external" target="_webapp">Call number</a>
```

...and it worked fine.

Could be that it needs both the `rel="external"` (to stop it from trying to AJAX the link) AND `target="_webapp"` so that it doesn't try to open Safari to handle the link.

Comment: I have been trying some stuff out and have found that I can easily use mailto and sms links and they work fine when testing on an iphone. But I still can't seem to get tel: to work. Is this a setting in phonegap perhaps? it doesn't seem to make sense!

Comment: Not sure... it could be a bug in jQTouch. I am using DataZombies fork: https://github.com/DataZombies/jQTouch

Comment: This is what I am using as well and it still doesn't do anything! Are you also using the initListIndices() call. This is linked to the s-scrollwrapper so be good to know if you are using this extension of the datazombies fork as well.  I recently had trouble displaying images from a remote source and had to edit the  phonegap.plist file to add an external host. Do you think it might be something like this that needs changing to get the tel link working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `target="_system"` on iOS for the `tel:` links to work.

Comment: An important tip that I've also just discovered, which may help people who come across this, is that on iOS, the value in the href must not have any formatting, such as spaces or brackets (eg. for area codes). So for example  it should be 18005558888, not 1800 555 888.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same issue, you can try the option `preventDefaultException` in the section **Advanced options** http://iscrolljs.com/#advanced-options

From iScroll 5 docs:

> options.preventDefaultException
>
> These are all the exceptions when `preventDefault()` would be fired
>   anyway despite the preventDefault option value. This is a pretty
>   powerful option, if you don't want to `preventDefault()` on all
>   elements with formfield class name for example, you could pass the
>   following:
>
> ```
> preventDefaultException: { className: /(^|\s)formfield(\s|$)/ }
> ```
>
> Default: `{ tagName: /^(INPUT|TEXTAREA|BUTTON|SELECT)$/ }`.

So you can just add an A tag to the tagName value:
`{ tagName: /^(INPUT|TEXTAREA|BUTTON|SELECT|A)$/ }`